# PHP: How to echo a line of if..else statement (Array, SQL)?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

First of all, I'm apologize for my broken English.

So, if there is information in database, and the data are masa=Pagi and masa=Petang, the output as first 'if'. Then, if the information in database has masa=Pagi or masa=Petang only, the output as second and third 'if' accordingly. Then, if there is no data in the database, the last else will be displayed. But now, my problem is, the data in database has masa=Pagi and masa=Petang, then my desired output should be the first "if" only. But why it display the first if and the second if?

---

**The desire output(in table):**

**Pagi  | Petang    |       Sehari  |**

**Sudah ditempah | Sudah ditempah |    Sudah ditempah**

**Current output(in table):**

**Pagi |    Petang  |   Sehari**

**Sudah ditempah | Tempah Sekarang | -**

**Sudah ditempah | Sudah ditempah | Sudah ditempah**

Here are the codes:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        { 
            $datas[]=$row['masa'];
            if(in_array("Pagi",$datas)&&in_array("Petang",$datas))
            {
                echo"
                    <tr>
                    <td>Sudah ditempah </td>
                    <td>Sudah ditempah</td>
                    <td>Sudah ditempah</td>
                    </tr>";
            }
            elseif(in_array("Pagi",$datas))
            {
                    $id=$row['id'];
                    $masa='Pagi';
                    $masa1='Petang';
                    $masa2='Sehari';
                echo"
                    <tr>
                    <td>Sudah ditempah</td>
                    <td><a href = 'formTempahan2.php?id=$id&masa=$masa1&tempat=$nama'> Tempah Sekarang </a></td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    </tr>";
            }
            elseif(in_array("Petang",$datas))
            {
                    $id=$row['id'];
                    $masa='Pagi';
                    $masa1='Petang';
                    $masa2='Sehari';
                    echo"
                    <tr>
                    <td><a href = 'formTempahan2.php?id=$id&masa=$masa&tempat=$nama'>Tempah Sekarang </a> </td>
                    <td>Sudah ditempah</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    </tr>";
            }


        }

        print_r($datas);
    }
    else
    {
        $id=$row['id'];
                    $masa='Pagi';
                    $masa1='Petang';
                    $masa2='Sehari';
        echo"
        <tr>
        <td><a href = 'formTempahan2.php?id=$id&masa=$masa&tempat=$nama'>Tempah Sekarang </a> </td>
        <td><a href = 'formTempahan2.php?id=$id&masa=$masa1&tempat=$nama'> Tempah Sekarang </a></td>
        <td><a href = 'formTempahan2.php?id=$id&masa=$masa2&tempat=$nama'> Tempah Sekarang </a></td>
        </tr>";
    }
```

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: @tadman so, do i have to change all the mysqli to mysql? or.. vice versa?

Comment: I mean specifically the long-form procedural style which is very easily confused with `mysql_query` by omitting a single `i`. The object-oriented form is much shorter, and cannot revert that way. I'd also advise you to look at PDO if you're not too heavily invested in `mysqli` as it's database agnostic and a lot more friendly to use in practice. Both work with MySQL. PDO works with many others.

Comment: For starters, move your `if{..} elseif {..}` blocks outside the while loop. Then tinker from there.

Comment: Whoa! Thanks for your help @Mr.Blue . it works !